# rsDriver function in RSelenium fails to establish a connection to the browser driver

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

### Problem

I am trying to establish connection to the chrome browser via RSelenium but keep receiving error messages or faulty outputs.

### What I've done so far

It is my first time using Selenium and RSelenium, therefore I've recently installed the JDK and the chromedriver and ensured that both the driver and my browser are on compatible versions. I've also added both the executable chromedriver file, as well as the JDK path to my environment variables.

### Code so far

#### try 1

`rs <- rsDriver(` 
`browser = 'chrome',` 
`chromever = '111.0.5563.64',` 
`extraCapabilities = list('webdriver.chrome.driver' = 'C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe'),` 
`verbose = F,` 
`port = free_port()` 
`)`

This code throws the following error:
*Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 14415 after 2212 ms: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.*

#### try 2

When substituting the input for the *port* parameter with the port 9515, which is apparently the default port for the chromedriver, like this:

`rs <- rsDriver(` 
`browser = 'chrome',` 
`chromever = '111.0.5563.64',` 
`extraCapabilities = list('webdriver.chrome.driver' = 'C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe'),` 
`verbose = F,` 
`port = 9515L` 
`)`

the code runs without an error message but does not open the chrome browser window. I've checked the task manager and can therefore rule out that its just a displaying error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
rD <- rsDriver(browser="chrome", port=4545L, chromever = NULL)
```

If you change verbose to TRUE you might additional error messages that might help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Hi, yes that works!! Thanks so much! Could you explain to me why you chose that port?

Comment: No particular reason :D I think `chromever = NULL` is more likely to be the reason the code started working.